# How i add image map in joomla article?

Tags: joomla1.5

I have to give link to multiple parts of the image.so please tell me how i can do it in joomla1.5.22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using JCE as your WYSIWYG editor right? If not, start by adding that. It's free and way better than TinyMCE. Once you have JCE installed, go to Components > JCE > Configuration and add `map[name],area[shape|coords|href|alt|title]` to the extended elements. Now you will be able to add the map code without losing it when you save plus you get a much better editor.